# to access the scratch folder of a SLURM cluster node

Tags: slurm, singularity-container, scratch-file

I would appreciate your suggestions and advise on the following please :

I am using a SLURM cluster and my colleagues have advised to run a singularity container on the cluster, and re-direct the output of the singularity container to a folder that is hosted in the /scratch folder of each computing node.

for example :

```
singularity exec --bind /local/scratch/bt:/output \
singularity_latest.sif run  \
-o /output
```

i would like to ask please : how can i access the "output" folder in the "scratch" of the computing node ? Thanks a lot !

bogdan

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `--bind` as a bit like a symlink. Running `ls /local/scratch/bt` on the host OS is equivalent to running `ls /output` inside the exec process.

```sh
mkdir scratch
touch scratch/file1

ls -l scratch
# total 0
# -rw-rw-r-- 1 tsnowlan tsnowlan 0 Jun  8 09:13 file1

singularity exec -B $PWD/scratch:/output my_image.sif ls -l /output
# total 0
# -rw-rw-r-- 1 tsnowlan tsnowlan 0 Jun  8 09:13 file1

# singularity also accepts relative paths
singularity exec -B scratch:/output my_image.sif touch /output/file2

ls -l scratch
# total 0
# -rw-rw-r-- 1 tsnowlan tsnowlan 0 Jun  8 09:13 file1
# -rw-rw-r-- 1 tsnowlan tsnowlan 0 Jun  8 09:16 file2
```